# How do I restart SharePoint Timer Service from command line?

Tags: sharepoint, command-line-interface

How do I restart SharePoint Timer Service from command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

net stop "Windows SharePoint Services Timer"

net start "Windows SharePoint Services Timer"

Answer (score 14):

SharePoint 2010:

```
net stop SPTimerV4
net start SPTimerV4
```

Answer (score 9):

I realize the OP is requesting a command-line solution, but using PowerShell (run as administrator), restarting the timer service is as easy as running:

`restart-service sptimerv4`

Comment: woo powershell!

Comment: Alternatively, one at a time: `Stop-Service SPTimerV4` then  `Start-Service SPTimerV4`

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint 2013: **net stop SPTimerV4** / **net start SPTimerV4**

SharePoint 2007: **net stop SPTimerV3** / **net start SPTimerV3**

SharePoint 2003: **net stop SPTimer** / **net start SPTimer**

Answer (score 2):

And for SP2010/2013 to do this for all machines:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.Instances | foreach { $_.Stop(); $_.Start(); }
```

Comment: What's about http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110928/spadminv4-which-could-not-be-contacted-in-deployment?noredirect=1#comment109814_110928 ? View comments: From my findings the $farm.TimerService.Instances doesn't implement start() or stop(), so this shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
REM - Save this in a .BAT file and set up a scheduled task that runs it periodically.
REM - This will recycle the SharePoint Timer Service, and also log it in the Event Viewer. 

EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /L APPLICATION /ID 777 /D "Starting scheduled task: SP timer restart."

net stop SPTimerV4
net start SPTimerV4

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
  EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /L APPLICATION /ID 777 /D "Scheduled task: Restart succeeded for the SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4 AKA 'SharePoint 2010 Timer').  ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%.  The restart is done by Scheduled Task, which runs the batch file: C:\_________________ every _ hours."
exit /b
) else (
  EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /L APPLICATION /ID 777 /D "Scheduled task: Restart failed for the SharePoint Timer Service (SPTimerV4 AKA 'SharePoint 2010 Timer').  ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%.  Please stop and restart the service manually and investigate the issue preventing the restart. The restart is done by Scheduled Task, which runs the batch file: C:\___________________ every _ hours."
)
EXIT
```